# Python Files(Write/Read)

Tags: python

So my proffessor has assinged us to write a file in Python that contains this..

```
37107287533902102798797998220837590246510135740250
46376937677490009712648124896970078050417018260538
74324986199524741059474233309513058123726617309629
91942213363574161572522430563301811072406154908250
23067588207539346171171980310421047513778063246676
89261670696623633820136378418383684178734361726757
28112879812849979408065481931592621691275889832738
44274228917432520321923589422876796487670272189318
47451445736001306439091167216856844588711603153276
70386486105843025439939619828917593665686757934951
```

Then..we have to read it line by line and sum each line seprately so in the end it will be something like this..

```
37107287533902102798797998220837590246510135740250 SUM: 214
46376937677490009712648124896970078050417018260538 SUM: 226
..etc...
```

Need help solving this.

P.S He also added this as a tip (`lines = f.readlines()`)
Also, if possible try to help with some basic python since we are still beginners.

Comment: what have you done so far? show us your attempt and any problems

Answer (score 0):

You best solution to is to read each line in (using the as hinted read lines). Remember though readlines() will fetch all of the lines for you and store them in a list of string lines.

```
lines = <filename>.readlines()
# Lines now holds and array of lines read by the file
# lines[0] = 37107287533902102798797998220837590246510135740250 
# lines[1] = 46376937677490009712648124896970078050417018260538
```

Now that you have your lines of numbers to add, go through each character in the line, cast it too a number and have a running total.

```
# Go through each line
for line in lines:
     total = 0
     # Go through each letter of that line (i.e. 3 then 7 then 1....)
     for letter in line:
          # Cast that letter to a number and add it to the total
          total += int(letter)
     # Append to the end of your line
     line += " SUM " + str(total)
```

With python it's really simple to accomplish this in just a few lines. I'll leave the opening the file up to you!

Comment: If it's about "just a few lines" I'll suggest this: `sum(map(int, line))`